# Append custom signature to all users in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

Is it possible to **APPEND** a custom signature to all user accounts (emails) in Outlook 2010? The accounts are managed on a Microsoft Server 2008 R2.

Most of the solutions I found simply create a "default" signature for all users, the problem with that is each user has their own custom signature and replacing all with a default will make uniqueness obsolete (for example the line where they put their name).

Keep in mind the appended content is HTML (img inside a link)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an Exchange server, and if so, which version?

Comment: Also, if you're not on Exchange Server, let us know if you're in a domain environment with directory services such as Active Directory where you have Group Policies. The Exchange Server method is probably the best but it depends on the version.

Comment: I'm not the server admin, how do I find this information?

Comment: Ask your server admin.

Comment: Hold Ctrl and right-click the Outlook icon down near your clock.  It should give you a "Connection Status" option.  click it, and in the box that opens up, scroll over to find the "Type" column.  What's listed there?

Comment: OK It seems to be Microsoft Exchange, now what?

Comment: Here are two articles of potential interest... [**Article1 - Using Exchange 2010 Transport Rule**](http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/how-to-set-up-email-signatures-on-exchange-server-2010/) and [**Article2 - Many Exchange Versions and More**](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm)... I could add to an answer but I'll not do so since I've not used nor tested to confirm all works as expected...

Comment: LMFAO_A_JOKE please submit an answer to get the points because you were the original person to post a link to the solution, it works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link may help.

[Setting up a Corporate Signature](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm)

Comment: I'll choose your answer since the article you provided explains in full length how to set up the custom signature / disclaimer in different versions of Exchange and shows the difference and limitation of each one, thank you.

Comment: You are more than welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for disclaimer feature of Exchange Server. Please review this TechNet article: [Configure a Disclaimer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876914(v=exchg.141).aspx). This way you'll be able to append any text (including HTML) to the end of users signatures.